# how to avoid 3 times duplicate bxslider after toggle();

Tags: php, jquery, bxslider

I'm trying to toggle a bxslider. but after toggling, the bxslider create images into 3 times.

```
<div style="float:left; width: 50%; height: 250px;" class="proj-5">                 
    <ul class="slider slider1 left">            
        <li style="background-image: url(http://local.fundhive.com/images/newsroom/8b/ea/8bea_fi_en8bea1754_ba81_df2e_7e83_1e617756c2e1.jpg);"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url(http://local.fundhive.com/images/newsroom/8e/45/8e45_fi_en8e455531_7618_2aba_3330_b372fdd99db2.jpg);"></li>
     </ul>                                              
</div>

<div style="float:left; width: 50%; height: 250px; display:none" class="proj-6">                 
    <ul class="slider slider1 left">
        <li style="background-image: url(http://local.fundhive.com/images/newsroom/30/15/3015_fi_en3015d80c_b110_8a62_3f58_7b94dc82e9fb.jpg);"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url(http://local.fundhive.com/images/newsroom/42/6b/426b_fi_en426b793f_a52f_d01d_1d53_53db562e8cde.jpg);"></li>            
     </ul>                                              
</div>
<script>
    $('.proj-property-id').click(function(event) {
            $('.proj-5').toggle();
            $('.proj-6').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

before toggling : 
[image]

after toggling :
[image]

Comment: >the bxslider create images into 3 times< What does that mean? When you are toggling the bxSlider, it's going from `display:block` to `display:none`?

Comment: after toggling the proj-5 and proj-6, proj-5 is going display:none. and proj-6 is disply:block. but the proj-6 has 2 imgs. after toggling, there are 6 imgs. and toggling again, the proj-5 also 6 imgs.

Answer (score 0):

When hiding and showing bxSlider, you should use it's [`redrawSlider()`](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4) method. The following is the relevant JQuery:

```
// <<$(document).ready()>> equivalent
$(function() {

  // instantiate bxSlider seperately  
  var bx1 = $('.bx1').bxSlider();
  var bx2 = $('.bx2').bxSlider();

  // Use `.on` method to handle binding to a dynamically created element.
  $('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {

    // Changed `toggle()` to `toggleClass()` because it's versatile.
    $('.layer').toggleClass('on off');

    // Ternary: if `.1st` has class '.on'| then: call bxSlider method redrawSlider() on bx1, if not, then:
    ($('.lst').hasClass('on')) ? bx1.redrawSlider(): bx2.redrawSlider();
  });
});
```

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(function() {
  var bx1 = $('.bx1').bxSlider();
  var bx2 = $('.bx2').bxSlider();
  $('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.layer').toggleClass('on off');
    ($('.lst').hasClass('on')) ? bx1.redrawSlider(): bx2.redrawSlider();
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.layer {
  position: relative;
}
.on {
  display: block !important;
}
.off {
  display: none !important;
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">


<button class='toggle'>Switch Sliders</button>

<div class='layer on 1st'>
  <ul class="bx1">
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150/fff/000?text=1">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150/fff/000?text=2">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>





<div class='layer off 2nd'>
  <ul class="bx2">
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150/000/fff?text=3">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150/000/fff?text=4">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```